# Understanding PayPal smart button authorization data flow and when funding failure can occur

Tags: paypal

I am using smart buttons with server-side API calls for the purpose of an authorization-capture type transaction. I already have orders being set up and passed back to the client for the PayPal popup to use.

I am trying to work out the handling of the user's authorization, as far as how that information eventually makes it to my server to be processed so that it can later be captured.

I currently use a webhook listening for the authorization notification with no further server calls being made from the smart button code, but was suggested in [a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67476475/paypal-orders-api-vs-payments-api-and-finding-better-documentation#67476823) that webhooks were overcomplicated for the purpose and to switch to just using the `onApprove` callback to send the data to my server directly from the client, but without much explanation of why that was better.

Other than being faster than the ~20 or so seconds it takes to receive the webhook notification, it seems like piping this kind of sensitive data through the client leaves it vulnerable to user tampering. Am I missing something? Am I just supposed to take the AuthorizationId and use it to fetch the transaction info safely from my server or something?

On a separate, but related note, the sample code in [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/) regarding funding failures seems to indicate that a funding failure can only be determined at the time of capture. Isn't the point of authorization to have the funds put on hold so that I can be sure they exist before I try to capture?

Am I misreading the documentation or does authorization just succeed regardless of the person actually being able to afford it? How can I tell, as early as possible, that there is a funding failure when I don't capture immediately? And where else in the authorization flow can errors occur, PayPal side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments there, the payer gives their approval on the client, in the browser -- so the notification to the server should come from the client. This way the server can act on the approval and authorize (or if `"intent":"capture"`, capture) the order and immediately reply to the client regarding whether it was successful or not.

That reply to the client should include (propagate) information about any errors, so that recoverable ones can be handled or non-recoverable ones can show a message to the user. Sample client-side error handling code is given here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls